# No connection with webservice Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, webservice-client

In my universal app i'm connecting with remote webservice. In windows phone I get WebException : The remote server returned an error: NotFound. The same application I have on windows 8.1 and there connection with webservice work fine.

What can be wrong?

Comment: You should post the code that raises the exception in order not to have only wild guesses as answers.

Answer (score 0):

this is not about a code. Is work fine on windows 8.1, IOS and android. It worked on windows phone a few days ago. Is a simple HttpWebRequest. The point is that I cant connect to webservice ONLY on windows phone. I checked on the two devices with this system. In addition, the webside which probably stands on the same server does not work on internet explorer in this devices. But when I open it in another browser website work fine.